# Instrumentation console missing?

Tags: lightning

Where did the Instrumentation console go? I remember seeing it in one of the orgs I was working, not sure if it was a developer org but I wanted to explore more on the same.

I googled and found very few resources about instrumentation console, strangely no official document from salesforce too :/.

Is there a way to enable it? Is it a request only feature?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've checked with someone within Salesforce. As it stands currently at the Spring '17 release the  Instrumentation Console is a tool used internally within Salesforce. It isn't generally exposed publicly.

From Google searches it does indeed appear to have been exposed publicly for a time around the Summer '16 release.

- [Salesforce Summer '16 Features](http://www.aboveandbeyondcloud.com/salesforce-summer16-features/)
- [What is Instrumentation Console for ?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kEo2IAE)
- [What is the use of instrumentation console in lightning experience?](https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/what-is-the-use-of-instrumentation-console-in-lightning-experience/)

---

I've never used the Instrumentation Console for comparison, but you might find some use in the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector Chrome Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm). This includes tools for identifying performance bottlenecks.

Comment: But I really liked it... Why can't we ever have fun toys?

Comment: @sfdcfox Somewhere within Salesforce there is a picture of a flaming dwarf (of the variety that comes in sevens) with the caption "Instrumentation Console" "This is why they can't have nice things!"